# Nodejs require different module depending on directory structure

Tags: node.js, directory-structure

I have two node projects who use the same directory:

```
projectA/
 |- app.js 
 |- projectB/
     |- app.js  
     |- node_modules/ 
           |- moduleX : version 1
 |- commonDir/ 
   |- commonModule.js
 |- node_modules/ 
   |- moduleX : version 2
```

`commonModule.js`:

```
    require("moduleX")
```

Both `projectA` and `projectB` do `require(commonModule)`. I expected that when I run `projectA` ( "node app" form 'projectA/'), version 2 will be loaded, and when I run `projectB`("node app" form 'prjoctB/') version 1 will be loaded. Unfortunately, in both cases it seems to run version 2.

Am I doing something wrong here?

**EDIT:**
I understand now that the node searches for the module according to the current module which did the 'require()', which make sense..

So, how can I choose on loading, which module version to run?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think commonModule.js is looking for the "closest" node_modules folder to it, which happens to be the version 2 one, even though it's run from both projects.

Comment: Your question is obscure because commonModule is somehow outside of node_modules. why is that? Isn't it actually mainDir and main.js??

Comment: Also, it's not clear when you say `run projectA` and `run projectB`,which file do you actually run?? The whole does not make sense to me.

Comment: You right. I wasn't clear enough. I edited it now. As for commonModule, It is just a module I've written and I want to use in both projects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding a module name in `commonModule` I'd set it so that I can give it a module object. For instance `commonModule` could contain:

```
module.exports = function(other_module) {
    return {
        foo: function () {
            return other_module.something("blah");
        }
    };
}
```

Then each project would then pass their own module to `commonModule`:

```
var commonModule = require("commonModule")(require("./moduleX"));

commonModule.foo();
```

`./moduleX` would be resolved according to each project, so no problem there. Your projects would have to be able to find `commonModule` but it seems you've already have this part covered.